# How can I define the type of a class param in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, html, documentation, web-component, jsdoc

I have a project that has some web-components classes and I also have a function that receive those components and register them into the window.
For example:

```
/**
* @param {} ComponentClass - class that extends HTMLElement
* @param {string} displayName - tag name to be used in html
*/
function registerComponent(ComponentClass, displayName){
  window.customElements.define(displayName, ComponentClass);
}
```

my question is: how can I correctly type ComponentClass? is there a way to describe that it's a class that extends HTMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

`CustomElementConstructor` is what you are after, e.g.

```js
/**
 * @param {CustomElementConstructor} ComponentClass - class that extends HTMLElement
 * @param {string} displayName - tag name to be used in html
 */
function registerComponent(ComponentClass, displayName) {
  window.customElements.define(displayName, ComponentClass);
}

class WCTest extends HTMLElement {}

registerComponent(WCTest, 'wc-test');
```